# How to summarize the meaning of the C++20 iterator-concepts?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, c++-concepts

If I want to visualize the hierarchy of the C++20 [iterator concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) I want to briefly explain in one line what each concept is about. Nothing precise, just a rough meaning (the precision is in the source... ;-) )

I have trouble coming up with a good "one-line summary" for

- input_iterator
- output_iterator
- forward_iterator

Here is my visualization:

```
digraph iter_concepts {

rankdir = BT;

node[shape=record];

indirectly_readable [label="{indirectly_readable|... = *it}"];
indirectly_writable [label="{indirectly_writable|*it = ...}"];
weakly_incrementable [label="{weakly_incrementable|++it, one pass}"];
incrementable [label="{incrementable|++it, multi pass}"];
input_or_output_iterator [label="{input_or_output_iterator|*it}"];
sentinel_for [label="{sentinel_for|for(x : ...)}"];
sized_sentinel_for [label="{sized_sentinel_for|for(... i&lt;sz ...)}"];
input_iterator [label="{input_iterator|}"];
output_iterator [label="{output_iterator|}"];
forward_iterator [label="{forward_iterator|}"];
bidirectional_iterator [label="{bidirectional_iterator| --it}"];
random_access_iterator [label="{random_access_iterator| it+=n, it-=n, it[n]}"];
contiguous_iterator [label="{contiguous_iterator| it ≍ pointer}"];


incrementable -> weakly_incrementable;
input_or_output_iterator -> weakly_incrementable;
sentinel_for -> input_or_output_iterator;
sized_sentinel_for -> sentinel_for;
input_iterator -> input_or_output_iterator;
input_iterator -> indirectly_readable;
output_iterator -> input_or_output_iterator;
output_iterator -> indirectly_writable;
forward_iterator -> input_iterator;
forward_iterator -> sentinel_for;
forward_iterator -> incrementable;
bidirectional_iterator -> forward_iterator;
random_access_iterator -> bidirectional_iterator;
contiguous_iterator -> random_access_iterator;

}
```

The resulting image is, which I am quite happy with, except for the missing boxes:

[image: digraph iter_concepts]

**Update:** I corrected the missing `forward_iterator -> incrementable` in the graph (not yet in the image).

Comment: The key feature of a forward iterator is the multipass guarantee (can revisit any element by preserving the old iterator; compare with e.g. `std::istream_iterator`, which can't revisit anything). `{input,output}_iterator` look self-explanatory to me, but maybe you can express it as `... = *it++` and `*it++ = ...`.

Comment: Also I think `forward_iterator` should have an arrow to `incrementable`. Also `sentinel_for` is confusing, because it doesn't need to be an iterator, yet you have arrows to and from it to iterators.

Comment: I would expect to see an explanation and a discussion of all iterator types and concepts in every advanced C++ textbook or reference. Sorry to hear that "you have trouble with finding a good explanation". Asking about recommendation for other learning resources is not appropriate for Stackoverflow, but does the one on cppreference.com help? The key to understanding all iterator concepts and types in C++ is to use a good C++ reference source to read their description and explanation. Coming up with some kind of a graph is not going to be very useful.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I read through the cppreference explanations and wanted to boil it down. I am aware the the one-liner will not be perfect. I find the graph useful, because I am someone who's learning process is supported by visualization. You know: "closing my eyes and having some kind of a map in my mind". That helps me a lot as a first orientation. A flat textual list can not do that. The graph representation is definitly not a perfect one, but I find it useful like a google map where you can zoom in into the details by looking into the reference. Later the map/graph not enough, I agree.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "forward to increment"... https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/forward_iterator Oh, yes! Thanks, I missed that one Thanks!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "The key feature of a forward ... is the multipass guarantee" -- well, thats covered by "incrementable" (when I corrected the graph). "{input,output}_iterator ... can be expressed by" very good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `input_iterator` is an `input_or_output_iterator` that is also `indirectly_readable`. Nothing special about that, it's just a more "specialized"/refined concept
- `output_iterator` is an `input_or_output_iterator` that is also `indirectly_writable`. Nothing special about that, it's just a more "specialized"/refined concept
- `forward_iterator` is an `input_iterator` that is also `incrementable` and `sentinel_for`. Nothing special about that, it's just a more "specialized"/refined concept

If you really need an example per box, just combine them intelligently to underline the sum of properties:

- `input_iterator` -> `++it; auto&& ref = *it;`
- `output_iterator` -> `++it; *it = value;`
- `forward_iterator` -> `auto bkp = it; ++it; auto&& ref1 = *it; auto&& ref0 = *bkp; ++bkp; *bkp == ref1;`

Comment: I don't _need_ an example per box, but I think it's useful for the visual orientation. but that might be an opinion. your suggestions are good.

Comment: `input_iterator` does not guarantee `auto& ref = *it;`.

Comment: I'll edit to `auto&& ref` to be more accurate

Comment: @Vivick does `auto&& ref = *it` in comparison to `auto& ref = *it` that `*it` might not support copy, but only move?

Comment: `auto&&` is a universal reference, not an rvalue reference. That's due to the iterators being free to have whatever `reference_type` they want (commonly `T&` which binds to `auto&` and `const T&` which doesn't)